# ionic ion-select-option don't display in dynamic json

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ion-select

I use ionic `ion-select` and `ion-select-option`, if json file is static, it shows ok, but if the json result is from http, it doesn't display well. If I use angular material select, its always works. 
[image]

```
MWS ={ MWSTA:[{  TB004: '188', TB005: '999', TB006: TRUE }]} ;selectedTB004 = '188';exhttp() {
this.http.post(this.http.xurl, this.para).subscribe(
  (record: any) => {
   this.search_json(  record.recordset  ); this.MWSTA = record.recordset ; });search_json(para: any) {      
  for (let i in para) {
    if (para[i].TB006) {
     this.selectedTB004 = para[i].TB004;
    }
  }      
}
```